# Eigen::aligned_alocator & std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, alignment, eigen, allocator

We are currently trying to move our codebase to use AVX instruction set, this entails making sure everything is aligned. I.e. applying the Eigen macros `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` or using `Eigen::aligned_allocator` when appropriate. One part is rewriting allocation of `std::shared_ptr` but for some odd reason, give a class `T`

```
class T {
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
  ....
  // Eigen fixed size matrices 
}
```

when I allocated a shared pointer like this

```
std::shared_ptr<T> instance(new T());
```

things works, but the following

```
typedef Eigen::aligned_allocator<T> Allocator;
std::shared_ptr<T> instance = std::shared_allocator<T, Allocator>(Allocator())
```

causes the aligned memory assertion in eigen to trigger, even though after stepping through I verified that the allocators allocation function where being called. This is on VS-2015 community edition. Is there something wrong with the second form ? Is this a bug in Eigen, Visual Studio ? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a C++17 compiler would make it all soooo much simpler...

Comment: Don't bother and use unaligned member types, for instance if you have a member of type `Matrix2d`, replace it by `Matrix<double,2,2,DontAlign>`. This will make everything much easier for you, your team and your users with likely unnoticeable performance hit.

Comment: @ggael, So you are implying that the effort that we would need to put in to make all the member types (mostly Transforms) aligned wouldn't be worth the pay off at all ? We're looking at a slim margin that is hard to estimate for the whole project anyway as we have a mix of sparse and dense operations, and if I understood correctly there is probably not a high gain on the sparse operations between AVX and SSE. We did some profiling and it was hard to quantify the gain anyway.

Comment: yes, first get something that works, then benchmark/profile carefully, and if it turns out that the bottleneck includes numerous unaligned AVX memory accesses, then you might start bothering about this details, but that's really unlikely to the case because only accesses to your member data will be unaligned, temporary and local variable will still be aligned.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar problem where I'm observing all the alignment info pages but still get unaligned accesses.

Comment: @oarfish I really don't remember, we were doing optimization on a larger system I think I made sure some of the local data was aligned but we never aligned all the heap allocated member data